# 'resulting in' vs 'resulting on'

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I'm a biologist and I'm writting a scientific text in english (not my native language). I always get corrections from my supervisors about using 'resulting in/on' in text (also not native speakers). Basically, they insist on using only 'resulting in', and I like to use 'resulting on' sometimes (but not always). I didn't think using 'resulting on' was wrong, and a 1h-long google search did not help as most posts are about 'resulting in vs resulted in'. So I'm asking here. Below are some examples from my text that got correct from 'on' to 'in'. Are these uses wrong? Are there specific rules for these cases? Is using 'resulting on' completely wrong or can it be a matter of personal preference? Would the meaning change depending on the preposition?

Examples:

1) Cold-water corals engineer soft sea beds in a similar fashion to shallow water corals, resulting **on** hotspots of biodiversity.

2) Seagrasses engineer saltmarsh communities by modulating hydrodynamic flow, resulting **on** distinct micro-habitats within their canopies for other species.

Comment: Why would you want to use *resulting **on*** there? No-one else does, as you seem to be already aware.

Comment: In English, we say that a verb _takes a preposition:_ it is followed by a phrase headed by a certain preposition. Does your English dictionary tell you what prepositions the verb _result_ can take?

Comment: Please, no more close votes here. This **isn't** "entirely answerable with a dictionary." Prepositions are tough. This is a fair question from a learner, and ELL was created to help learners with such conundrums.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - I just checked six different online dictionaries, and none of them included an exhaustive list of prepositions that the verb could take. Moreover, several example usages were provided, and these included the prepositions _of, before, with, from_, and _in_. If you can't empathize with the learner on this one, I think it's time to migrate your efforts to ELU. This site was set up largely to get away from the kind of callousness you have been exhibiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One tool you might want to add to your research toolkit is Google's Ngram viewer. A quick comparison of [**resulting in** and **resulting on**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=resulting%20in%2Cresulting%20on&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresulting%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresulting%20on%3B%2Cc0) shows that the phrase **resulting on** barely exists. Use **resulting in**.

Comment: You can also click on those links at the bottom of the Ngram to see the usages in context. The ones for "resulting on" are interesting, and actually bolster the argument that the phrase is incorrect, because, in many cases, the "resulting on" hits are for phrases that actually use "resulting in," such as: _...switching frequencies **resulting** on one hand **in** power loss reduction, on the other hand **in** an increase unintentional harmonic amplitude_.

Answer (score 3):

As a native North American English speaker, I can conclusively say that "resulting on" is **literally never, ever used**. There is no difference in meaning; it's simply that one is correct and the other is not.

It may help if you think of "resulting in" as a single unit, not the word "resulting" and your choice of preposition. And granted, there are ways to use "resulting" by itself, but if it's getting a preposition, it's gonna be "in".